# XC8 : Connot use defined variable

Tags: c, variables, xc8

I define a struct as following:

```
struct _connection_info_t{
char unique_name[5];
char ip[16];
char port[5];
}WIFI_connection_info_g[2],zz[3];
```

And use WIFI_connection_info_g[0] variable in "sprintf" function :

```
sprintf(buffer,"AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"%s\",%s",WIFI_connection_info_g[0].ip,WIFI_connection_info_g[0].port);
```

When i compile above code,the compiler generate following error :

> wifi_tempalte.h:290: error: (1402) a pointer to eeprom cannot also point to other data types

But when i change "sprintf" function and use "zz" variable like following:

```
sprintf(buffer,"AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"%s\",%s",zz[0].ip,zz[0].port);
```

It compile successfully.

Note 1:
My target device is 16f1829

Note 2:
Compiler version is 1.30

Comment: Please ensure your code is sufficiently *complete* for us to reproduce the issue. In this case, we would have to guess in order to fill in many blanks, but you won't get accurate help if we resort to guessing, and we'll be wasting our time. As a result, you're not likely to get an answer to this question. See [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information.

Comment: Also important to note that the MPLAB-C compiler manuals state that these compilers have defects... Have you read about those defects? Technically they make these compilers non-C, but you've added a C tag. This is kinda like asking for advice on [the B programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_(programming_language)#Examples), using the C tag... The languages may be similar, but they have subtle yet devastating differences, and a standard C programmer is unlikely to be able to help without first familiarising themselves with the manuals...

Comment: Names at file-scope starting with underscore are reserved for the implementation. You must not declare them in your code.

Comment: autistic - its *supposed* to be C89

Answer (score 0):

Probably too big to declare in one go.
You may have to declare different instances of it in different C files.
xc8 can get confused. The compiler is targeting an 8 processor and it
tends to keep things
in the same page (256 RAM blocks) where it can. It can get confused though.